# ArangoDB and advanced vertex-cut graph partitioning

Tags: graph, partitioning, sharding, arangodb

I am searching for a graph database that will store a really big graph in a distributed fashion.

This graph will be processed by an algorithm (too complex to be implemented with a Pregel-like model) that will run on many workers in parallel. Thus, the graph needs to be partitioned (vertex-cuts will be used as suggested in many papers for power-law graphs) and this process will have such an important impact on performance that I want to handle it manually.

After some searches, I think that ArangoDB with its Sharding capacity can help me. I will create one shard per-cpu-per-worker, and those will be filled with one graph partition each. I don't know if ArangoDB offer any support for cut-vertex but this can be handled by hand. The very important question is: since my partition algorithm may move vertex and edges between partitions to keep the communication overhead at minimum, can ArangoDB handle that? If I update the shardingKey (an Integer ranging 1-#partitions I think) will ArangoDB move a vertex or an edge?

Thanks.

Feel free to recommend other strategies if you thing there are better ones.